# How does autowiring of custom spring data (mongo) repositories configured with java config work?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I use Spring Data Mongo with repositories. In my xml-configuration everything works fine. Now I want to use Java configuration instead of xml-configuration. This is my java configuration for the repositories:

```
@Configuration
@EnableMongoRepositories
public class DefaultMongoDbFactoryConfig extends AbstractMongoConfiguration{

    @Value("${db.name}") private String dbName;

    @Inject
    private Mongo mongo;

    @Bean
    protected MongoDbFactory defaultMongoDbFactory() throws Exception {
        return new SimpleMongoDbFactory(mongo, dbName);
    }

    @Bean
    protected MongoTemplate defaultMongoTemplate() throws Exception {
        return new MongoTemplate(defaultMongoDbFactory());
    }

    @Override
    protected String getDatabaseName() {
        return dbName;
    }

    @Override
    public Mongo mongo() throws Exception {
        return mongo;
    }

    @Override
    protected String getMappingBasePackage() {
        return "foo.bar.repository";
    }

    @Override
    public MongoTemplate mongoTemplate() throws Exception {
        return defaultMongoTemplate();
    }


}
```

I have a repository with a custom implementation:
Interface: MyRepository (extends the custom interface)
CustomInterface: MyRepositoryCustom
Implementation: MyRepositoryImpl

I have another configuration file with the component-scan annotation:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"foo.bar"})
@Import(DefaultMongoDbFactoryConfig.class)
public class AppConfig {

}
```

Now spring does not seem to autowire the custom implementation on startup. I get "No qualifying bean of type". Is this not supported in java config or am I missing something?

**EDIT**: I'm using spring data mongo 1.3.1 and spring 3.2.4

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In which package does `DefaultMongoDbFactoryConfig` reside? If you don't explicitly state a package in the `@EnableMongoRepositories` annotation, we only scan the package of the annotated configuration class. If this is in `foo.bar.config` and you have your repos in `foo.bar.repositories` no repository interfaces will be found.

Comment: Thank you for the hint, Oliver. I added the basePackages value to the annotation. This works!